# Different behaviors from Decryption method in java

Tags: javascript, java, java-security

i am using decryption alogirthm RSA with public and private keys from certification .

```js
var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
var publicKey = "example";
encrypt.setPublicKey(publicKey);
var data = encrypt.encrypt(value);
console.log(data);
return data;
```

```
public static String getDecrypted(String data, String Key)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey pk = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
            .generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(Key.getBytes())));
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk);
    // byte[] encryptedbytes =
    // cipher.doFinal(Base64.encodeBase64(data.getBytes()));
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(data)));
}
```

i am using front end encryption and in main method  encryption . the encrypted values from two sides are getting correctly . but when i call it from web 
i get another values like that

```
EAQ�žÃqÈ›@Á¢éz¡?�4zsHD-U€� 
 KÉ¢a`Õ³=jö`›=šúFhU;••˜ü®2¿¶žñÛ¤lÉê×)§?]¾–`n_üÙ&1ï)ðeÈž‹x¯ø¬#;ýp&   Ê*í~ý¾´çVõF¯±ë©yñÌ±©w_f'úHâ¬’#™G™|¦ý¹j"Ìç8=ŽRÉž[££4™s#àâ
```

and the value at the end

Comment: Well am not sure how you are sending this String to UI. But it looks like it has something to do with character encoding. you can specify  UTF-8.

Comment: i used UTF-8 but same result . and for string values are same to the method but different outputs

Comment: In java it will be same. Cipher takes care of it.  How are you passing String to UI. ??

Comment: it is String given to method getDecrypted(String ,String)